# How to add more fields using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 3 input fields with **+Add More** Button. I want to add more fields when **+Add More** button is pressed.

When New field will create there should be a remove button to remove newly added row and new row can be create by using **+Add More** button.

For that I am using following html and jQuery code but can't get the idea how to add / remove fields !

**html and jQuery Code**

```
<div id="tab_logic" class="after-add-more">
    <div class="col-md-4">                                
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Logger Name</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Logger Name" name="lg_name[]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Logger Serial Number</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Serial Number" name="lg_sl[]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Modem Serial Number</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Modem Serial Number" name="lg_md_sl[]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="remove-button"></div>
</div>  
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group change">
        <label for="">&nbsp;</label><br/>
        <a class="btn btn-success add-more">+ Add More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="more-feilds"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add-more").click(function(){ 
        var html = $("#tab_logic").html();
        $(".more-feilds").append(html);        
    });

    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents("#tab_logic").remove();
    });
});
```

**Update :**

I have updated my html and jquery code. Now I have +Add More button. When I pressed the button it's adding 3 new input fields which I want. But I want to add remove button to each newly created 3 fields to remove it.

How can I do this ?

Comment: instead of `$(".change").html` use `$(".change").append` to add more elements. `.html` will replace the existing elements in the selected area.

Comment: however, $(".change").append will add a new button to _all rows_ _every time a new row is added_. Maybe better to have the markup there already but hidden, and just use this code to show it.

Comment: Hello guys.. I have updated my code using `append` function. Now It's adding new row with 3 input fields. How can I add a remove button to each newly created row to remove it ?

Comment: "fields" not "feilds" :-)

Comment: `$("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents("#tab_logic").remove();
    });` will always remove the first row no matter which Remove is pressed. HTML IDs must be unique.

Comment: @ADyson It's typo :)

Comment: Every time you create a new row it will add an extra "Add More" button. most UIs I've seen only have one "Add" button, but then 1 "Remove" button per row. I think it might be confusing to users to have multiple Add buttons, you might want to consider moving that to the top or something, outside the row.

Comment: @ADyson You right. I need only one add more button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the below logic. this will clone the first div.after-add-more and add the remove button on the html.

P.S : i have removed the id to avoid duplicate ids in html.ID attribute is not required for this functionality, hope that is not an issue with you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click",".add-more",function(){ 
        var html = $(".after-add-more").first().clone();
      
        //  $(html).find(".change").prepend("<label for=''>&nbsp;</label><br/><a class='btn btn-danger remove'>- Remove</a>");
      
          $(html).find(".change").html("<label for=''>&nbsp;</label><br/><a class='btn btn-danger remove'>- Remove</a>");
      
      
        $(".after-add-more").last().after(html);
      
     
       
    });

    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".after-add-more").remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="after-add-more">
  
    <div class="col-md-4">                                
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Logger Name</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Logger Name" name="lg_name[]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Logger Serial Number</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Serial Number" name="lg_sl[]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Modem Serial Number</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Modem Serial Number" name="lg_md_sl[]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group change">
            <label for="">&nbsp;</label><br/>
            <a class="btn btn-success add-more">+ Add More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. But when a new row added I want to show only remove button not add more button to each field. Add more button only show on first row. Is that possible ?

Comment: @shibbirahmed yeah thats very simple to do, i am prepending the remove button html instead we can replace it. Updated the code, have a look

Comment: Exactly what I want. 100 Like :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.append()` instead of `.html()`. The [.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function insert content to the end of each element in the set of matched elements and [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) will replace the existing elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add-more").click(function(){ 
        var html = $("#tab_logic").html();
        $(".after-add-more").after(html);
        $(".change").append("<label for=''>&nbsp;</label><br/><a class='btn btn-danger remove'>- Remove</a>");
    });

    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents("#tab_logic").remove();
    });
});
```